# returning reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I was looking at [this](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/examples/returnrefpointer.htm) link about returning reference to a pointer. According to this, we have to return reference to a static or global variable. My question here is, in case we create memory block inside a function using new, why application will crash since memory allocated using new is permanent until deleted? I wrote below code to test this and it crashes and if I make ptr static inside the function, there is no issue.

```
int* &returnPtrByRef(int numElements)
{
    int *ptr = new int(numElements);
    return ptr;
}

int main (void)
{
    int num=5;
    int *&ptrRef = returnPtrByRef(num);
    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < num; cnt++)
      *(ptrRef + cnt) = cnt * 2;
    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < num; cnt++)
      cout << *(ptrRef + cnt) << '\t';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The memory block isn't gone, but your pointer to it is (resulting in a leak).

Comment: BTW `*(ptr + cnt)` is exactly the same as `ptr[cnt]`, so prefer the short meaningful way of writing that.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to think of references as syntactic sugar for pointers. So let's rewrite your function using a double pointer, instead of a reference to a pointer:

```
int** returnPtrByRef(int numElements) {
  int *ptr = new int(numElements);
  return &ptr;
}
```

Here, we can see that we're actually referring the pointer to the piece of stack allocated memory that points to the memory we allocated on the heap. Once the function returns, this stack allocated memory (8 bytes to hold the pointer), no longer exists.

Comment: What does "8 bytes" add here?  It's wrong on most architectures.

Comment: It's to more explicitly differentiate from the `sizeof(int) * numElements` memory block.

Comment: Hum, I got the issue. I was thinking from following angle and in the below case, though pointer is a local variable, its value is pointing to the block created. So I think there is no issue in this usage. Correct me if I am wrong (But I guess such usage is not suggested)
int* returnPtr(int numElements)
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = new int(numElements);
    return ptr;
}

Comment: That's fine. You're returning the pointer itself by value. You're returning a  pointer to stack memory. You're basically doing `int* returnPtr() { int x; return &x; }`